# In Wordpress, how can I change the destinations of my links dependent on what page user is on?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the problem that I am using a theme where the navigation is simply 'scrolling' to a given part (eg. #contact) when pressed. However, I have implemented some seperate subpages that exits this scrollable page and thus renders the navigation ineffective.

My question is, how can I change the destination of my links or maybe change the menu entirely when users are on these subpages?

I should clarify that all the pages that need 'the new' navigation use a different page template called full_width.php. But since it is using an include header function I can't just replace the navigation.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple solution based on templates.

```
 if ( is_page_template('full_width.php') ) {
    //menu for full width page
} else {
    // Returns false when 'full_width.php' is not being used.
    wp_nav_menu( $args );//read for args in codex to make menu you want.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Valery, but this bit makes my nav right, and I do not understand it at all: http://pastebin.com/9YHj7zxy